# Getting "Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket" with capybara

Tags: ajax, qt, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a rspec test that uses javascript

so I added `, :js => true` to the spec

But now it fails and I get

```
Getting "Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket"
```

The scenario is:

```
scenario 'user checks off a task as done', :js => true do
  visit root_path
  puts page.body
  find('input#task_done.boolean[type=checkbox]').set(true)
  visit root_path
  expect(page).to_not have_content "Task1"
end
```